# How to fix dependency resolution errors?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, dependency-resolution

I'm developing a game in libgdx and I'm using an external jar to work with JSON, and I know libgdx has it's own but I've worked with this jar before and I know how to use it. Anyways I added it to my build.gradle in my root directory and synced. But now when I try to build the project, I get this big error message:

```
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.BaseDescription found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.Description found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.Factory found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.Matcher found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.StringDescription found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.AllOf found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.AnyOf found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.DescribedAs found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.Is found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsAnything found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsInstanceOf found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsNot found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsNull found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.core.IsSame found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.internal.ArrayIterator found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.internal.SelfDescribingValue found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
Duplicate class org.hamcrest.internal.SelfDescribingValueIterator found in modules hamcrest-core-1.1.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1) and junit-4.10.jar (junit:junit:4.10)
```

I have no idea what this means, or what this org.hamcrest is that has duplicates. Here's my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.0.9'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.8'
        

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "ShootOut"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.10'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.8'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        api "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-android:$gdxVersion"
        
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        
    }
}
```

The only thing I added was the "implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'" to the dependencies in my core project.
Any idea how to fix this error? Or what even is causing it?

Comment: One of your libraries is including `JUnit` (probably `junit-dep`, which is including `hamcrest-core`. Another library is also including `hamcrest-core` somewhere down the line.

Comment: Solved this yet?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yes! I ended up excluding JUnit

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below lines into app `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    // Some other stuffs
    configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'org.hamcrest' // This removes all other versions of `org.hamcrest` if gets duplicated from all the artifacts.
    }
    // other stuffs
}
```

Comment: I ended up having to add :configurations { compile.exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"}, and it worked however, I'm still confused to why it didn't run into this problem before? Since the jar I added didn't contain the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to add :

```
configurations { compile.exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"}
```

in the core section in build.gradle,  and it worked.